# Can smarty block names be derived from smarty variables

Tags: php, smarty, block

I would like to define smarty block names according to smarty data, but I can't seem to do it.
Example:

```
{foreach $array as $code}
  {block name=block_$code}
     <div id='{$code}'></div>
  {/block}
{/foreach}
```

My purpose is to extend a specific block_$code block by a child template.  Is this possible or is there some other trick I could use to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the following link from 2011 indicating that this wasn't possible at that time.  I suspect it still isn't:

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19805&highlight=block%20variable%20name

The good news it that I was able to figure out how to make my code work without it.  I wanted to be able to override just one of the divs defined by the foreach.  Here's how I can do it:

Parent:

```
{foreach $array as $code}
    {block name=code_loop}
        <div>Normal Stuff</div>
    {/block}
{/foreach}
```

Child:

```
{block name=code_loop}
    {if $code == 'code of interest'}
        <div>New Stuff</div>
    {else}
        {$smarty.block.parent}
    {/if}
{/block}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`{assign}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) block and the [`cat`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl) modifier. For example

```
{foreach $array as $code}
    {assign var=foo value="block_"|cat:$code}
    {block name=$foo}
        <div>
    {/block}
{/foreach}
```

N.b. I've not tested this, but it should work. You might also be able to short-circuit this and just use `{block name="block_"|cat:$code}`.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to recognize blocks with names defined in variables.

Comment: Weird. What about the latter form?

Comment: Nope.  Either it doesn't create the blocks at all or the name of the block isn't obvious.  I'm thinking that the stuff withing the {block} definition element doesn't allow any dynamic values.  I tried to do things like `{block name={"block_"|cat:$code}}`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Weird, assign should be able to do that. I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.